# Is Here-api compatible with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, here-api

Is there any plugin for Flutter Framework?
If it does not exist, has the Here Team plans developing an official plugin?

Comment: I don't know Here-API but https://developer.here.com/develop/rest-apis should work fine. It's just HTTP requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here doesn't provide any separate support for Flutter Frameworks nor have any plugins yet. But you should be able to use our Android/iOS SDKs in your framework. https://developer.here.com/develop/mobile-sdks

Comment: But can I access this SDK without a plugin?

Comment: Yes, you can access.

Answer (score 2):

You can check my prof-of-conept. 
https://github.com/etzuk/flutter_here_maps.

Comment: I tried running your example and I'm having difficulties: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60319195/flutter-says-it-could-not-resolve-project

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

HERE now provides a Flutter package. You can find it in your [developer account](https://www.developer.here.com/products/here-sdk).

Or else you can use this: https://pub.dev/packages/here_maps_webservice. So far, it does only contain

- Geocoding
- Reverse Geocoding
- Geocoding Autocomplete
- Explore Nearby Places
- Explore Popular Places

Comment: Great, but all of them are in beta so can't be used in production

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a working prof-of-conept of a HEREMaps Flutter plugin. However, it shares the same limitations as the first version of Google Maps that has been using a Surface-Draw approach. In detail: the HEREMaps plugin currently relies on placing platform overlays on top of a bitmap snapshotting widget for creating the illusion of in-line compositing of HEREMaps views with Flutter widgets. This works only in very limited situations where
- the widget is stationary
- the widget is drawn on top of all other widgets within bounds
- touch events within widget bounds can be safely ignored by Flutter

Currently Flutter does NOT allow to create a native (Maps / any UI) plugin without these limitations. Even the Google Maps plugin from Google itself works only on Android as of now.

Once these limitations are removed, I can create a fully featured HERE Maps plugin :-)

Its not that hard to use platform code within Flutter. However, I would prefer a direct C++ binding to avoid the Objectiv C / Java to Native bridge overhead. Ideally, the DART Code bindings could be autogenerated from C++ code.

I am sure if enougth developers are asking for a HERE Maps Plugin for Flutter, HERE will provide one. Currently Flutter has some limitations that makes it impossible to provide a Maps plugin that does not have the limitations I mentioned. For sure, that is one techncial reason HERE has not provided an official plugin yet.
Btw. I am not aware of any working maps plugin for Flutter without these limitations.

Comment: Hello! Can not use the Here SDK from Flutter without a plugin?