# Update on Premium SDK for Flutter?

Tags: flutter, here-api

I saw the question asked back in November 2018 ([Is Here-api compatible with Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53163098/is-here-api-compatible-with-flutter)) and it sounded like a Flutter plugin would be coming in the future. I was wondering if there's an update on when to expect a Flutter plugin and if there's a plan for a premium version of the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

We do not have a plugin for Flutter but like the previous answers, you can directly use our Android Mobile SDK in your Flutter project. You can just add our `HERE-sdk.aar` file to your project as done in this blog:
http://a5.ua/articles/integration-android-aar-library-flutter-project (note: not HERE related blog)

Comment: thank you for the update. i currently can't reach the linked website, but I was able to use the instructions here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682847/how-to-manually-include-external-aar-package-using-new-gradle-android-build-syst)

Comment: i don't have enough rep to comment on the other answer, but can you please explain how to use the SDK without creating a plugin? everything i've seen says you need to create a plugin to communicate with the Android and iOS SDKs.